# dual mouse input - simulate multi-touch

Tags: input, mouse, touch, multi-touch, gesture

Ive always thought this would be cool, and now the OS technology seems it could really make it easy to implement-

Is there a known/easy way to hook up dual mice as inputs to a multi-touch enabled OS, such as Win7, and use one in each hand to simulate two hands (or fingers?) on the screen? This would make it easy to stretch, rotate, etc and simulate a lot of the gestures used on touchscreens.

I think it might be alot of fun for certain kinds of games, and many artistic apps as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows, you can use the [Direct Input API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectInput) included in DirectX 8+ to read the independent input of as many mice as desired. Easiest way is to get ahold of several USB mice and connect them all at once.

Also, you don't need to have a 3D view whatsoever to take advantage of DirectInput, you can use access the API from a regular Win32 or .Net app.

For instance, the PC game [Ricochet Infinity](http://www.ricochetinfinity.com/) allows two mice as input for its two player co-op mode.

Comment: Interesting, I thought that all mice input, despite how many mice are connected, were piped into one mouse move event for the OS, so that even if you have 5 mice plugged in and moved them all at once, to the OS it will only look like one mouse has moved. I wasn't aware there was even a game that supported multiple mice per computer.

Comment: Here is a fairly old game I made with multiple mouse support:
http://chozabu.net/stuff/marble/oldmarble.zip
The multi-mouse version (marbleVS.exe) is windows only, but it wouldnt have to be that way if I had used many mouse! http://www.icculus.org/manymouse/

Answer (score 2):

A platform independent solution is for multiple mouse input is http://www.icculus.org/manymouse/
Like the Windows-only solution posted, This still wont let you do multi-touch in chrome, or the android emulator (Though, both should be relatively simple to implement), etc.

If you want to simulate multi-touch in other peoples software, things are a little trickier.

Just about any non-windows system can support multiple pointers for the main interface: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-Pointer_X

Chrome supports simulating touch events, unsure on multi-touch

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to simulate mouse input to touches pointer with [Multi Touch Vista](http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/)